# Javascript add blob to html input value

Tags: javascript, blob, custom-data-attribute, zip.js

I create a blob from an array containing base64 with [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/core-api.html)

```
var strMsgArray = JSON.stringify(msgArray);
var blob = new Blob([strMsgArray], {
  type : "text/json;charset=utf-8"
});
zipBlob("message.json", blob, function(zippedBlob) {
    // do stuff
});

<input id="messageArray" type="hidden" />
```

This gives me the desired result in the console but now I need to add it to form input value and submit

It doesn't work as is. It doesn't work when I stringify. What is the correct way?

Comment: can you add your blob and html tag where you are adding that blob?

Comment: I added the basic html input but I don't know what you're asking for with blob. Like what's shown in the console?